# bisect mirror doesn't work

Tags: modifiers, mirror

im trying to mirror bisect a mesh.

I used ctrl - and got a cutout I wanted in the first shape.
the applied mirror in the first ( cutted) shape.
the cutout doesn't happen on the other side.
if I toggle bisect on Y, it shows the mirror on the other side in wireframe , but not in viewport shading.
what is weird is that I have another project that I followed one tutorial in, and in that project , all works fine when I follow the same procedure..

[image]

[image]

thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: maybe your object is not correctly oriented, what does it give if you apply the rotation (Ctrl A)? If this is not the problem, please share your file